# Help with this proof

Tags: proof-writing

> *If the sets $A$ and $B$ are bounded above and $A\subseteq B$ and $A$ and $B$ both have supremums, then $sup(A)\le sup(B)$*

Came across it in my textbook and was wondering how to prove it. It looks pretty simple. Thanks!

Comment: assume $sup(A)>sup(B)$. That means there are elements of the set $A$ that between $sup(A)$ and $sup(B)$ ($x \in A$, $sup(B)<x<sup(A)$)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** show that every upper bound for $B$ is also an upper bound for $A$.